# Trigger container onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to rewrite the following code so that when you click on button "next" or something, the next container opens and the current one closes. The same thing goes for the button "back".

Unfortunately I don't know exactly how to rewrite the code to get the wanted result, because my preferences lie the most in backend and I'm still pretty new to JavaScript and jQuery.

Here's my current code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.trigger').not('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').hide();
        $('.trigger').click(function() {
            var trig = $(this);

            if(trig.hasClass('trigger_active')) {
                trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle(500);
                trig.removeClass('trigger_active');
            } else {
                $('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').slideToggle(500);
                $('.trigger_active').removeClass('trigger_active');
                trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle(500);
                trig.addClass('trigger_active');
            };
        return false;
        });
    });
```

And the class:

```
    <div class="trigger">
        <table width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
            <tr>
                <th align="left">User Information</th>
                <th align="right"><font size="1">(click to expand)</font></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle_container">
        <table width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Username<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
                <td align="right"><input name="username" id="username" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Benutzername" required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
                <td align="right"><input name="password" id="password" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Mindestens 6 Zeichen" required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
                <td align="right"><input name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">E-Mail<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
                <td align="right"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><input name="back" type="button" value="Back" style="background: transparent; border-color: #8E6516; color: #FFFFFF; width: 135px;" /></td>
                <td align="right"><input type="button" name="next" value="Next" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I modified the code according to what you told me in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to display several tables, but one at a time. Here is a solution based on jQuery as required.

I created several tables and added css classes :

- .trigger-next and .trigger-back to "Back" and "Next" links
- .hidden to hide the tables at the beginning.

Then, on every "Back" or "Next" click, the code parses the tables and decides what to show or hide.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var next = true;

  function displayOtherScreen(elem, direction) {
    if(next && !$(elem).hasClass("trigger_active")) {
      next = false;
      $(elem).addClass("trigger_active").slideToggle(500);
    } else if($(elem).hasClass("trigger_active")) {
      next = true;
      $(elem).removeClass("trigger_active").slideToggle(500);
    }
  }

      
  $('.trigger').click(function() {
    // click on "(click to expand)" link or "Next" links
    if($(this).hasClass("trigger-next")) {
      $('.toggle_container').each(function(elem){ 
        displayOtherScreen(this, "next");
      });
    }
    // click on "Back" links
    else {
     // read ".toggle_container" elements backwards
      $($(".toggle_container").get().reverse()).each(function(){ 
        displayOtherScreen(this, "back");
      }); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="trigger trigger-next">
    <table width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
      <tr>
        <th align="left">User Information</th>
        <th align="right"><font size="1">(click to expand)</font></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle_container trigger_active">
    <table width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Username<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
        <td align="right"><input name="username" id="username" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Benutzername" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
        <td align="right"><input name="password" id="password" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Mindestens 6 Zeichen" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
        <td align="right"><input name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">E-Mail<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
        <td align="right"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right" class="trigger trigger-next"><input type="button" name="next" value="Next" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div class="toggle_container hidden">
      <table width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">2nd screen<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="username" id="username" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Benutzername" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="password" id="password" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Mindestens 6 Zeichen" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">E-Mail<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="trigger trigger-back"><input name="back" type="button" value="Back" style="background: transparent; border-color: #8E6516; color: #AAA; width: 135px;" /></td>
          <td align="right" class="trigger trigger-next"><input type="button" name="next" value="Next" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle_container hidden">
      <table width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">3rd screen<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="username" id="username" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Benutzername" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="password" id="password" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Mindestens 6 Zeichen" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Password<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" type="password" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">E-Mail<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
          <td align="right"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="trigger trigger-back"><input name="back" type="button" value="Back" style="background: transparent; border-color: #8E6516; color: #AAA; width: 135px;" /></td>
          <td align="right" class="trigger trigger-next"><input type="button" name="next" value="Next" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit : I replace the .hidden class by the .trigger_active class on the first table : this way the first table is visible and active at first. I modified the condition in the function displayOtherScreen accordingly.

I also removed the "Back" button from the first table, otherwise, it would have displayed the last table when clicking it. But it really is up to you to add it again.

Hope this solution fits your needs.

Comment: That's (almost) what I expect. The first table needs to be expanded already. I tried different variants of your code, but none of the seem to fit. Either it expands the second table beneath the first one or it doesn't expand at all. Any solution?

Comment: I modified the code according to what you told me in comment.

Comment: I experimented a bit with the Code you provided. I deleted the "click to expand" Area completely, since when you clicked on it, the whole thing slid back up. The code you provided is now exactly what I needed. Thanks alot!